# How do I set up a call on each list item within map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

In my react component where I try to render a list based on material-ui List component, I have the following problem.

I loop through an array of contact objects to render a list of ListItem, but I want to be able to handle click event on each List item.

I use the onTouchTap prop and tries to call my onSelectedContact method but how do I pass in the current contact object from the map function?

```
{this.props.contacts.map(( contact, i ) => <span key={i}>
  <ListItem
    key={i}
    primaryText={contact.name}
    onTouchTap={this.onSelectContact?????}
  />
}
```

Comment: `this.onSelectContact.bind(this, contact)`

Comment: @Maxx that's not a comment, that's an answer.

Comment: @Ven i thought it's not good to write one-line answers

Comment: Thank you very much, it works like a charm. Could you elaborate on whats going on? Does it means we bind the method to the current ListItem during the map loop?

Comment: bind creates new function with given context and params. first parameter is context, others are parameters

Comment: @Maxx I suppose `onSelectContact` is defined in the upper scope so would this work? `onTouchTap={onSelectContact()}`. Arrow functions remove the need of `bind` in that case.

Comment: @Maxx explain why, link to `.bind`, done.

Comment: @anoop you need bind here in 2 cases. 1 to just bind some params to function (as in question), 2 to bind context. there is a mistake in your example (`onTouchTap={onSelectContact()}`). You execute function and pass its result. Right is `onTouchTap={onSelectContact}` you pass just handler. When `ListItem` does `this.props.onTouchTap()` its changes its context, it means you can't (for example) do `this.setState()` in parent component handler because context in handler is ListItem's props object. Sry for my english )

Comment: @maxx yeah that was a typo. I understand it now. Thanks for the clarification. You explained it well.

Comment: @Maxx I was able to do the same this way, https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LkKdpq?editors=0011

Comment: @anoop and what the point? you call function that calls another function. Whats "the same" you did?

Comment: @Maxx are you meaning that it is wrong? I tried to use it "without" an explicit bind

Comment: @anoop 1. you should not declare functions at render function (it declares at every render), 2. You have a stateless components in your example it means you can't use component's state. What your handler gonna do in real world code?

Comment: @anoop you don't need bind in your example because you don't use context of function (`this`)

Comment: @Maxx, yes your last comment is clear. I was just testing out with a stateless function but not intended to check its performance. Anyway I understand it very well now. Thanks..

Answer (score 2):

`this.onSelectContact.bind(this, contact)`